# Can not create a Path from a null string in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, toolrunner

I am using ToolRunner to run my Job

```
public class ToolRunner1 extends Configured implements Tool {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
System.out.println("In main");
 int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new ToolRunner1(), args);
 System.exit(exitCode);
 }

 @Override
public int run(String [] args) throws Exception {

Configuration conf = getConf();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);    
Path p1 = new Path(conf.get("input1")); //Receving a NULL Value
Path p2 = new Path(conf.get("input2")); //Receving a NULL Value
Path p3 = new Path(conf.get("output")); //Receving a NULL Value
if (fs.exists(p3)) {
 fs.delete(p3, true);
}
Job job = new Job(conf, "ToolRunner");
job.setJarByClass(ToolRunner1.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job,p1);
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, p3);

boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
return(success ? 0 : 1);
 }

}
```

Command that I ran:

```
hadoop jar toolru.jar -D input1=/home/sreeveni/myfiles/tab -D input2=/home/sreeveni/myfiles/tab -D output =/home/sreeveni/myfiles/OUT/Toll
```

But getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from a null string
```

Am I doing anything wrong?
Please suggest.

**Edited**
As chris suggested I updated my code. and works fine through eclipse IDE
When I ported my jar to cluster it gives the same error

```
hadoop jar toolru.jar tool.ToolRunner1 -D input1=/home/sreeveni/myfiles/tab -D input2=/home/sreeveni/myfiles/tab -D output =/home/sreeveni/myfiles/OUT/Toll
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want:

```
Configuration conf = getConf();
```

instead of

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
```

Comment: Yes Chris. I edited my code.Now it is running perfectly in standalone mode(using hadoop lib in eclipse IDE).But when i tried to run same jar in 8 node cluster again showing the same error.Again it is receving a null value in all conf.get.

Comment: while running in cluster I use this command<hadoop jar toolru.jar tool.ToolRunner1 -D input1=/home/sreeveni/myfiles/tab -D input2=/home/sreeveni/myfiles/tab -D output =/home/sreeveni/myfiles/OUT/Toll> It wont work in cluster and once I remove my mainclass along with the command it works fine. What if i need to include the classname also?

Comment: I think the OUT directory does not exist in hadoop. Can you let me know what does this command return hadoop fs -ls /home/sreeveni/myfiles/OUT/

Comment: @PradyumnaMohapatra: Now my issue is "while running in cluster I use this command<hadoop jar toolru.jar tool.ToolRunner1 -D input1=/home/sreeveni/myfiles/tab -D input2=/home/sreeveni/myfiles/tab -D output =/home/sreeveni/myfiles/OUT/Toll> It wont work in cluster and once I remove my mainclass along with the command it works fine. What if i need to include the classname also? "

Answer (score -2):

Try this,
Instead of using -D option, use command line arguments and then use String [] args, for creating path(new Path(args[0]) etc).

This might give you a clue on -D option usage (whether -D option is available for user defined key value pair or the option is given only to add configuration(core-*.xml) level changes).

How you're executing in eclipse? Can you give the arguments applied during running(run configurations)?

Comment: Using ToolRunner is the better way of coding Amit

Comment: Now my issue is "while running in cluster I use this command<hadoop jar toolru.jar tool.ToolRunner1 -D input1=/home/sreeveni/myfiles/tab -D input2=/home/sreeveni/myfiles/tab -D output =/home/sreeveni/myfiles/OUT/Toll> It wont work in cluster and once I remove my mainclass along with the command it works fine. What if i need to include the classname also?

Comment: Reason to ask, to test with arguments is to make sure other stuff are fine with your configurations. But looks like toolrunner is not able to parse the command line properly. Try with giving only 2 values: input1 and output.

Comment: but i am able to run them with out classname